# Apps simply hide upon switching apps with Alt+Tab

Tags: 12.04, unity

After upgrading to 12.04 and being on Unity, I am having this strange problem.

Say I have opened a few apps, e.g., Chrome, GNUCash, GIMP, etc., and I am presently working on GNUCash. When I press Alt+Tab to switch some other app, the app I was working on, e.g., GNUCash simply hides somewhere and I cannot find it where it is. However, in System Monitor, it still shows up.

Can someone help me figure out where these apps are getting hidden upon switching to other app.

Answer (score 0):

They might be on one of the other workspaces. In the unity bar on the left, near the bottom, you'll find workspace switcher.

You can also use the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+ to move between the workspaces.

Hope you can find it there!

Comment: Nope, the apps are not going to other workspaces. I have checked all the workspaces but they aren't there.